# boost python after compile and run gives me segfault

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  boost::array<int, 4> arr = {{1,2,3,4}};
  cout << "hi" << arr[0];
  return 0;
}
```

compile using :

```
g++ a.cpp -o a -I /usr/include/python2.7/ -lboost_python -lboost_system -shared -fPIC
```

the run ./a  and it gives me:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I think it is something related to boost python library, if I remove

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
```

and compile with

```
g++ a.cpp -o a
```

then ./a, everything works well. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `-shared` flag on the executable:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5479166d518fb207

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ a.cpp -o a -I /usr/include/python2.7/ -lboost_python -lpython2.7 -lboost_system -fPIC
```

I added -lpython2.7 and now its working